# multiple access to bitfields without changing value, performance?

Tags: c++, performance, bit-manipulation, compiler-optimization, bit-fields

given a struct with bit-fields, for example :

```
struct
{   
    long f0: 6;
    long f1: 6;
    long f2: 2;
    long f3: 2;
} S;
```

should there be a performance difference between the following codes:
1-

```
const int f0=S.f0,f1=S.f1,....;
//multiple calculations that use f0,f1,...., for example
int x=f0*f0;
```

compared to 
2-

```
//multiple calculations that use S.f0,S.f1,... directly, for example
x=S.f0*S.f0
```

I'm not asking as a premature optimization, but I wan't to know if today's compilers are capable of knowing that f0,... don't change between different parts of the program or not.

Comment: They might be.  Only way to know is to try it out.  [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) is a very handy tool for doing this.

Comment: Why do you think that copmilers could be "knowing that f0,... don't change between different parts of the program or not"?The shown code would allow to tell that, because it is so static and simple. But the more dynamics come in (functions, conditions, call via function pointers which are dynamic) the less possible it gets. You are not asking about the shown code, are you? Is ther any `const`involved?

Comment: No other way to know if it will be optimized but to check the codegen.

Comment: @NathanOliver,SergeyA unfortunately I don't know assembly to be able to compare the output.
Yunnosch No, not about the shown code, it's just an example to demonstrate what I meant.

Comment: No better time to learn then :) You can at least see if you get the same assembly or not.  If they output is the same then you know both options get optimized to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

#### Expect the highest competence from your optimizer

This is of course completely implementation dependent.  But as a general principle, you can expect an optimising compiler to generate similarly optimized code in both case.

Why ? Because basically, on many target CPUs, working with bit fields requires just some binary operations (shifting right and left) on the original value. The optimizer then can optimize these expression (e.g. optimizing redundant sub-expressions), like with any other operations in an expression.

#### Practical experiment:

Take the sequence:

```
x=S.f0*S.f0;
y=S.f0*S.f1;
```

The (relevant part of )[code generated](https://godbolt.org/z/V3EOV2) by GCC 8.3 is:

```
  1)  movzx   eax, BYTE PTR S[rip]     ; load 8 bit of data data and make it 16 bits
  2)  sal     eax, 2                   ;  get rid of the 2 bytes to keep only the 6
  3)  sar     al, 2
  4)  movsx   edx, al                  ; clone the value in second register
  5)  mov     eax, edx
  6)  imul    eax, edx
  7)  mov     DWORD PTR x[rip], eax

  8)  movzx   eax, WORD PTR S[rip]     ; load 16 bits
  9)  sal     eax, 4                   ; get rid of 4 bits (so remain 12)
 10)  sar     ax, 10                   ; get rid of 10 bits on other side (so remain 6 next)
 11)  movsx   eax, al
 12)  imul    eax, edx                 ; reuse register previously loaded
 13)  mov     DWORD PTR y[rip], eax
```

Now for the other alternative:

```
const int f0=S.f0,f1=S.f1;
x=f0*f0;
y=f0*f1;
```

you'll get the [following code](https://godbolt.org/z/GDb_dL):

```
  1)  movzx   eax, BYTE PTR S[rip]
  8)  movzx   edx, WORD PTR S[rip]   ; but in another register
  2)  sal     eax, 2
  9)  sal     edx, 4                 ; but other register
  3)  sar     al, 2
 10)  sar     dx, 10                 ; but other register
  4)  movsx   eax, al
 11)  movsx   edx, dl                ; but other register
  5)  mov     ecx, eax               ; but other register
  6)  imul    ecx, eax               ; but other register
 12)  imul    eax, edx
  7)  mov     DWORD PTR x[rip], ecx  ; but other register
 13)  mov     DWORD PTR y[rip], eax
```

Additional experiments show that it's the same for loop optimisation: the compiler is able to extract the bitfield access code out of the loop and reuse several times the values extracted.

***Hint:***  for the sake of the tests, in view of the abilitites of the optimizer, you need to trick a little bit so that your testing code doesn't get optimized away.  For this purpose, I've made x and y volatiles (so that they are written event if the value is never used).  I also initialized the structure with a non existant external function, so that the compiler is not able to do constant propagations.

Of course, this is only true if the compiler is sure that S doesn't change between the successive expressions.  If the compiler can't assume that (e.g. you call a function using a reference or a pointer to S) it would have to reload S.fx everytime, makeing it slower than the initial loading into a const value.